# Textbox two way binding not triggering

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol, inotifypropertychanged

I have a tab control with 3 objects, 2 lists and a textbox. The text box is bound two way :

```
<TabControl x:Name="tcTabs" ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ReceivedMessages}" DisplayMemberPath="Raw" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0" />
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" DisplayMemberPath="Nick" Visibility="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource UserListVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFBBBBBB" Width="130" />
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentInput, Mode="TwoWay"}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFBBBBBB" Height="22" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Backing object :

```
public string CurrentInput
{
    get
    {
        return _currentInput;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _currentInput)
        {
            _currentInput = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, when I change the text and click another tab it does not update the backing field (does not even hit the setter), however if I change then click the listbox it does...

Any reason for this odd behaviour?

Comment: This also may be the cause of not point of the property in OnPropertyChanged method like `OnPropertyChanged("CurrentInput")`. Please ignore if already tried this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not an odd behaviour and has been asked multiple times before. Read about [`Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx), also see the remarks of [the respective property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx) you bind.

Comment: I opologise for my ignorance but "When used in data-binding scenarios, this property uses the default update behavior of UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus." -- when I click another tab does it not "Lose Focus" and thus should trigger an update?

Comment: @MuhammadA: Not necessarily, WPF has focus scopes, if every tab has its own scope then the `TextBox` has still focus. It could also be possible that the control is removed before it can lose focus.

Comment: Yes and that is more complicated problem than whatever else has been asked multiple times. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MuhammadA: There are questions relating to that, especially when using DataGrids in TabControls. You should be able to handle some event on the TabControl to move focus before switching tabs.

Comment: @MuhammadA: Also if you cannot devise your own solution you should not only ask for the *reason of the behaviour*, which basically is the update triggering.

Comment: Why not? It definately is strange that the tab click does not trigger a lost focus, I am pretty sure it did in winforms, now I am new to WPF so its only reasonable I think it is odd.

Comment: @MuhammadA: I was just saying that i only gave the reason because you asked specifically for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this problem (Twoway Binding) by manual trigger the databinding engine using

```
DataContext = this;
```

Comment: hello, would be nice if you provide more context for this sole line of code. The question have a solid context, i'm sure if you  elaborate this answer you'll will help much more people.